# SHA-256 and node-red

Tags: algorithm, ssl, ssl-certificate, node-red, sha256

I was wondering if it is needed the SHA-256 algorithm to generate a certificate request for configuring SSL in node-red or if another algorithm could be used. I have looked in the node.js library and I don't find any information about this.

Do you know about this?

Comment: You need an SSL certificate? Do you want it self-signed or signed by a reputable CA? Is it for a domain?

Comment: Self-signed. I have already created the certificate authority. And it is for an IP address, I'm not going to purchase a domain.  Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: You can do that [with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl) if you need a self-signed one. IDK if that would work with your DIY CA, but that will make a self-signed certificate for you.

Comment: In fact the command that I am going to use is" openssl req -new -sha256 -key node-key.pem -out node-csr.pem" but I don't understand why it has to be with the sha256 algorithm

Comment: It doesn't have to be SHA 256. [Here](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/openssl/openssl.1ssl.en.html#Message_Digest_Commands) are a bunch of other ones it supports. Of course, just because an algorithm is listed does not mean it is secure. So don't just go pick a random one. That said, Node-red may want a specific one. You could try some other algorithms, and then write an answer to your own question if they work (or if they don't, too)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special algorithm needed, you can load any (valid or self-signed) SSL certificate to node-red.

That said, if you need a valid SSL cert for a node-red instance, this is one (simple) option you can evaluate: [link](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/free-and-ssl-secured-access-to-your-node-red-instance-running-on-a-raspberry-pi/64112)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: edited. I hope now it is a better answer.